# Dbeaver freezes in an infinite loop

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver, fly

I have a postgresql database that is hosted on fly.io
I had been using the database with the plpython3u ext without any problems, until Friday.

the database simply freezes on this run:
[image]

and it doesn't come out of it

I realized that to generate this loop the code must have:
Syntax error
Error in the call (SELECT * FROM wrong_name_table) that is, a wrong name when calling the table
Return error in functions

If I don't cancel this loop, it stays until dawn and doesn't stop, so I force a stop in this query, and I look at the details of the errors and I get this:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.checkClosed(PgConnection.java:907)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createStatement(PgConnection.java:1776)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCConnectionImpl.createStatement(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:413)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:131)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:1)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.DBUtils.createStatement(DBUtils.java:1453)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.DBUtils.makeStatement(DBUtils.java:1419)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:558)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$1(SQLQueryJob.java:491)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:190)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:498)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:934)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:3940)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:123)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:190)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:121)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:5142)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Can anyone tell me what it could be? On my localhost I don't receive any errors like this, only on the production database